# Error using Composer

Tags: php, windows, yii2, composer-php

Recently I installed Composer because it's the prefered way to install the Yii Framework, but it seems i can't make use of it and i don't know why.

This is an example of what happens when i use composer commands:
    C:\wamp\www>composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0-beta2"
    Changed current directory to C:/Users/Nuno/AppData/Roaming/Composer

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Composer\Package\Version\VersionParser::pa
rseLinks() in C:\Users\Nuno\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\fxp\composer-asset-p
lugin\Repository\VcsPackageFilter.php on line 270
```

Comment: Docs are outdated, you should install the latest version of `fxp/composer-asset`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest stable version of Composer Asset Plugin installed before running `composer install` or `update`:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
```

It's covered in official docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#installing-via-composer).

Comment: I'd even go as far as `"fxp/composer-asset-plugin:*"`